# Start-AzVM : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired Error

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-authentication, azure-runbook

I made a Runbook in an automation account in Azure that will start and stop my VMs, but I keep getting credentials error while I am setting up the credentials in the runbook.

The error:

```
Start-AzVM : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials. At Start-StopVM-Workflow:59 char:59 + + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzVM], ArgumentException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StartAzureVMCommand
```

The runbook code:

```
{
    Param 
    (    
        [String] $Action
    ) 

################################################################     
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Connect-AzAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
################################################################

    if($Action -like "Stop") 
    { 
        $AzureVMs = Get-AzVM | ? {$_.resourcegroupname -notlike 'lab*'}
        Write-Output $AzureVMs.count
        #$AzureVMs = Get-AzVM | ? {$_.resourcegroupname -notlike 'lab*' -And $_.Tags["DontShut"] -notlike "Yes"}

        #Write-Output "Stopping VMs"
        foreach -parallel ($AzureVM in $Azurevms)
        { 
            $temp = "Stop VM: " + $AzureVM.name
            Write-Output $temp
            $AzureVM | Stop-AzVM -Force
            $count = $count+1
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $AzureVMs = Get-AzVM | ?{$_.Tags["AutomaticStart"] -eq "Yes"}
        Write-Output $AzureVMs.count
        #Write-Output "Starting VMs";

        foreach -parallel ($AzureVM in $AzureVMs) 
        { 
            $temp = "Start VM: " + $AzureVM.name
            Write-Output $temp
            $AzureVM | Start-AzVM 
        }
    } 
}
```

I tried using the `Connect-AzRMAccount` command but its no use.

If anyone knows a fix for this I'd be really thankful.

**EDIT:** After trying to update Az.Accounts and Az.Compute modules I still got the same error plus four new errors:

```
Install-module : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' or newer version of NuGet provider is installed. At Start-StopVM-Workflow:13 char:13 + + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Module], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotInstallNuGetProvider,Install-Module
```

```
Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or 'C:\Users\Client\AppData\Roaming\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider now?" At Start-StopVM-Workflow:13 char:13 + + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HostException
```

```
Install-module : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' or newer version of NuGet provider is installed. At Start-StopVM-Workflow:12 char:12 + + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Module], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotInstallNuGetProvider,Install-Module
```

```
Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or 'C:\Users\Client\AppData\Roaming\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider now?" At Start-StopVM-Workflow:12 char:12 + + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HostException
```

My current runbook script looks like this(Changes are in lines 12-14):

```
workflow Start-StopVM-Workflow
{
    Param 
    (    
        [String] $Action
    ) 

################################################################     
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
        Install-module -Force -name Az.Accounts
        Install-module -Force -name Az.Compute
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Connect-AzAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
################################################################

    if($Action -like "Stop") 
    { 
        $AzureVMs = Get-AzVM | ? {$_.resourcegroupname -notlike 'lab*'}
        Write-Output $AzureVMs.count
        #$AzureVMs = Get-AzVM | ? {$_.resourcegroupname -notlike 'lab*' -And $_.Tags["DontShut"] -notlike "Yes"}

        #Write-Output "Stopping VMs"
        foreach -parallel ($AzureVM in $Azurevms)
        { 
            $temp = "Stop VM: " + $AzureVM.name
            Write-Output $temp
            $AzureVM | Stop-AzVM -Force
            $count = $count+1
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $AzureVMs = Get-AzVM | ?{$_.Tags["AutomaticStart"] -eq "Yes"}
        Write-Output $AzureVMs.count
        #Write-Output "Starting VMs";

        foreach -parallel ($AzureVM in $AzureVMs) 
        { 
            $temp = "Start VM: " + $AzureVM.name
            Write-Output $temp
            $AzureVM | Start-AzVM 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Navigate to your automation account -> `Run as accounts`, check if the run as account was expired?

Comment: Azure run as account is up to date but Azure classic run as account isn't. Though I don't think Azure classic is related.

Comment: Your script should work, try to use the latest version of `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Compute` modules, in the `Modules` of your automation account, uninstall the old ones and install the new version.

Comment: Could it solve your issue?

Comment: I tried it and it added four more errors that I added to the question above.

Comment: Please don't modify your original script, it works, I have test it. You need to update the modules in the `Modules` of your automation account in the portal, not in the code,  uninstall the old ones and install the new version.

Comment: Oh, alright will try that!

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Nope, now I'm getting the "Start-AzVM : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials." error again... Maybe I should use az login instead of Connect-AzAccount?

Answer (score 0):

Your Runbook should ideally work with just the `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Compute` modules. I was able to test and execute your snippet with the Account I have.

I'd suggest you to cross-check your current Automation account/Runbook configuration, or create a new one as follows:

- [Create an Automation Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-account) with `Create Azure Run As account` option enabled.
- [Import `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Compute` modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#powershell-gallery) from the Powershell gallery via Azure portal.
- [Create a Powershell Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook) with your current code.
- Test it.

If the issues recur despite doing this, please let me know and we can investigate further.

More about using Az modules with Azure Automation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/az-modules).